# Compute the difference of three series (motivated by an integral formula)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let
\begin{align}
L&=2^{3 / 2} \pi^{4} \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n, m, k=1}^{\infty} n^{2} m a_{n} a_{m} b_{k}\left(\delta_{m, n+k}+\delta_{n, m+k}-\delta_{k, n+m}\right) \\[5pt]
R_{1}&=2^{3 / 2} \pi^{4} \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n, m, k=1}^{\infty} n^{3 / 2} m^{3 / 2} a_{n} a_{m} b_{k}\left(\delta_{m, n+k}+\delta_{n, m+k}+\delta_{k, n+m}\right) \\[5pt]
R_{2}&=\frac{1}{2} 2^{3 / 2} \pi^{4} \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n, m, k=1}^{\infty} n^{1 / 2} m^{1 / 2} k^{2} a_{n} a_{m} b_{k}\left(\delta_{m, n+k}+\delta_{n, m+k}-\delta_{k, n+m}\right),
\end{align}
where the $\delta$ denote the Kronecker delta.

How can we compute $$L-R_1-R_2 \ ?$$

The motivation for this computation comes from an integration by parts formula analyzed on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382207/using-fourier-series-to-prove-int-01-u-xxxu-x-eta-int-01-u-xx2-e/382212?noredirect=1#comment971906_382212).

Comment: how might we compute this without knowledge of $a_n$ and $b_n$ ? if these have a known functional form, and decay sufficiently rapidly for large $n$, the sum can be evaluated, but otherwise I don't see how any progress can be made.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker You can assume that $a_n$ is the Fourier coefficient of a function belonging to some fractional Sobolev Space and $b_k$ are the Fourier coefficients of a smooth function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the Kronecker delta's we can carry out the summation over $k$,
$$L-R_1-R_2=2^{3/2}\pi^4 \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_na_m\biggl[\bigl(m n^2-(m n)^{3/2}-(m-n)^2 \sqrt{m n}\bigr) b_{|n-m|}$$
$$-\bigl(m n^2+(m n)^{3/2}-(m+n)^2 \sqrt{m n}\bigr) b_{n+m}\biggr].$$
Without further knowledge of the coefficients this cannot be evaluated further.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we can assume $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k^2(1+(\pi k)^{3}) \le K < \infty$ and that the $b_k$ are the Fourier coefficients of a smooth function. Would this help with the estimate?

Comment: @Dal -- I am afraid this is "the most detailed answer" possible without explicit knowledge of how the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ depend on $n$; for example, how is $b_{|n-m|}$ related to $b_{n+m}$?